# Get contact details to titanium from native iOS contact app

Tags: ios, titanium, contacts, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm new to Titanium.
Currently I'm working on a project in this the user needs to use the contact details from iOS contacts App.

My `app.js` looks like this

```
Window = require('ui/handheld/ApplicationWindow');
var win = Window();
win.open();
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'Show Contacts',
    width : 100,
    height: 50,
});
win.add(button);
button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    Titanium.Contacts.showContacts({ });
});
```

When I click on a button the following code is displayed:

[image: Contact list]

And when I select an contact the detail is displayed on the other screen:

[image: Contact details]

But I don't want this, When the user selects an individual contact the details should be passed to my `app.js` file. And no need to go to the details page.

Is there any way to do this ?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it.

I used the following code:

```
button.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    Titanium.Contacts.showContacts(values);
});
var values = {cancel:function(){}};
values.fields = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'phone'];

values.selectedProperty = function(e) {
                var cn = e.person.firstName; 
                var sn = e.person.lastName;
                alert('Name'+cn+' '+sn);
};
```

Reference : [Titanium Contacts](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/81741/titaniumcontactsperson-sorting-on-android-and-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're missing a declaration of function to be called when a person is selected:

```
Titanium.Contacts.showContacts({/*missing selectedPerson callback object*/});
```

You can read more on what parameters can be passed into `showContacts` method [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/showContactsParams).

Comment: I got it before you answered... From this link http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/81741/titaniumcontactsperson-sorting-on-android-and-iphone. Thanks for the reply dude :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var parms = {
animated : true,
selectedPerson : function(e) {
    alert(e.person);
}
```

`};
Titanium.Contacts.showContacts(parms);`

You will get the details of selected person in `e.person` object. that can be passed to app.js etc according to your requirements. i just showed it in the alert.

Comment: @SAIR how can i get the contact details ? I just need all the numbers for a contact ...

Comment: var parms = {
selectedPerson : function(e) {
alert(e.person)
}
};
Titanium.Contacts.showContacts(parms);

you can pass selectedPerson Listener as parameter and you will get the detail of selected person