# Open contact picker to specific contact

Tags: ios, titanium, contacts, appcelerator

I have an iOS mobile application that I am building in Appcerator Titanium and I want to open the contact picker to a specific contact. Is that possible?

I have all the contacts loaded in a table view and it seems like I should be able to say, "Open the contact picker and show contact with this id", but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021114/get-contact-details-to-titanium-from-native-ios-contact-app. I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Contacts-method-getPersonByID

The appcelerator Contacts documentation says you can get a user by recordId or search for users by their name

Comment: This just returns a Titanium.Contacts.Person object though. I want to show the contact picker. Basically, I want to exactly replicate the UI for when you click on a specific contact in the contact picker. I'd rather not write the code to do that if there is some way to just tell the picker to open to a certain contact.

Comment: I would look for a module in the marketplace, it looks as if the UI doesnt support that functionality